# How to properly implement React Transition Group for Page Transitions

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom, react-transition-group

I've been tearing my hair out all day trying to get this to work.  What I'm noticing is that for whatever reason, the transition classes (classNames="fade") never get applied to the page elements.  So when I navigate from one page to another, for a brief period (the timeout period) both of the page components will be displayed.

**What I should have for 600ms...**

```
<div class="RTG"> 
    <div class="page fade-appear fade-enter fade-enter-active"> <!-- 
destination component HTML --></div>
    <div class="page fade-exit fade-exit-active"> <!-- start component HTML --></div>
</div>
```

**What I get is..**

```
<div class="RTG">
   <!-- "fade..." classes never applied to the child nodes" -->
   <div class="page"> <!-- destination component HTML --></div>
   <div class="page"> <!-- start component HTML --></div>
</div>
```

And then after the 600ms timeout, I'm left with...

```
<div class="RTG">
   <div class="page"> <!-- destination component HTML --></div>
</div>
```

**NOTE 1**: I put the "RTG" className on the TransitionGroup component simply to verify that my "page" class components are actually direct descendants of the TransitionGroup component.  Doesn't exist for any other reason.

**NOTE 2**: I'm using react-transition-group@2.4.0 because I have a compatibility issue with the latest version.

**AppRouter.js**

```
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';
import PublicRoute from './PublicRoute';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group'



const AppRouter = () => (
    <Router history={history}>
        <Route render={({location}) => {
            return (
                <TransitionGroup className="RTG">
                <CSSTransition 
                    key={location.key}
                    timeout={600}
                    classNames="fade"
                >
                    <Switch location={location}>
                        <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={ExpenseDashboardPage} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
                        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
                    </Switch>
                </CSSTransition>
           </TransitionGroup>
            );
        }} />

    </Router>
);


export default AppRouter;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ 
    isAuthenticated, 
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <div className="page">
                <Header />
                <Component {...props} />
            </div>
        ) : (
            <Redirect to="/" />
        )
    )} />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.uid
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

**PublicRoute.js**

```
export const PublicRoute = ({ 
    isAuthenticated, 
    component: Component,
    ...rest
}) => (
    <Route {...rest} component={(props) => (
        isAuthenticated ? (
            <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
        ) : (
            <div class="page">
                <Component {...props} />
            </div>
        )
    )} />
);

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: !!state.auth.uid
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PublicRoute);
```

**Applicable CSS Styles**

```
.page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.fade-appear,
.fade-enter {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fade-appear-active,
.fade-enter.fade-enter-active {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: opacity 300ms linear 150ms;
}

.fade-exit {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

.fade-exit.fade-exit-active {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 150ms linear;
}
```

Comment: How about timeout={{ enter: 1000, exit: 1000, }} in your <CSSTransition /> props?

Comment: Well, the problem isn't the timeout (and that's a valid way to express it) the problem is the CSS not being applied to the transtioning child nodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you will need to wrap `<Switch>` inside a parent component.

`CSSTransition` works as it will try to inject `classNames` to its children as props. Which means the child element will need to take these props and pass on as `classNames`. Thus you will need to wrap `<Switch>` into another component to make sure this mechanism works properly.

[Edit on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-sea-66nfe?fontsize=14)

```
const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router>
    <Route
      render={({ location }) => {
        return (
          <TransitionGroup className="RTG">
            <CSSTransition key={location.key} timeout={600} classNames="fade">
              <div>
                <Switch location={location}>
                  <PublicRoute path="/" component={LoginPage} exact={true} />
                  <PrivateRoute
                    path="/dashboard"
                    component={ExpenseDashboardPage}
                  />
                  <PrivateRoute path="/create" component={AddExpensePage} />
                  <PrivateRoute path="/edit/:id" component={EditExpensePage} />
                  <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </CSSTransition>
          </TransitionGroup>
        );
      }}
    />
  </Router>
);
```

Comment: Hey Chris - that was the trick!!  There was nothing in the docs or in the demo that I watched that mentioned that.  I'd almost given up on it, so thanks alot.  You da man!

Comment: You are more than welcome Scotty. Please mark my answer as useful when you have a chance : )

Answer (score 2):

Making fluid beautiful full page transitions can be tricky.

Most solutions implement it on the `route` component.

## Link Approach

Define the animations on a custom Link component. When user navigate, the next page will enter, and the current one will leave.

```js
<Link
  to="/some-path"
  transition="glide-right"
/>
```

Of course, for that you must create your own link...

So you can use packages that does that, like [react-tiger-transition](https://pedrobern.github.io/react-tiger-transition/).

## Demo

[image: demo-gif]

(I'm the author)